# How to open "System > Administrator" -menu?

Tags: appmenu

Ive come across many times to need to open the "System > Administrator" -menu, but I havo no clue how? I searched on google that youd need to press ALT + F1 + S, but nothing happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "System" menu in modern versions of Ubuntu.

Just open the Dash (using Ubuntu button on the Launcher or Win key on your keyboard) and start typing program's name that you want to launch.

Comment: there is, see [hey_sanchos's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76018/how-to-open-system-administrator-menu/76023#76023)

Comment: This is about to be true. There is no System menu on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can access settings, provided in the former "Administrator" menu by typing "System Settings" in Dash, or by clicking "power" or "power cog" button in the top-right corner on the panel and choosing "System Settings".

[image]

"Hardware" and "System" groups contain required applications.