# How do I go to the System Menu in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open “System > Administrator” -menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76018/how-to-open-system-administrator-menu)

I don't know how to go to the System menu on Ubuntu 11.10

Example for what I'm talking about: `System -> Administration -> Disk Utility`

Comment: What DE are you using `gnome-shell` or `unity` ?

Comment: I recommend that you click on the Ubuntu icon on the top left to open the Dash and then type Help in the search bar to find and load the Ubuntu Desktop Guide.